# How to access the characters in getline() in C

Tags: c, getline

I'm trying to access the text from getline() in order to scan it for a special character. The program reads from a file and creates another one but, I have to remove the comments from the first file and print it to the second file without the comments.  In this case I need to be able to read all '%' and remove everything to the right.  This is part of my homework and I'm not looking for someone to complete it and cheat.  I just need to find a way to get the line stored in a char array so I can loop through and find a '%' if it exists.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


    FILE *fp, *fp2;

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read = 0;
    //int i = 0;

    //line = test;

    fp = fopen("taxDemo.m", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("taxDemoNoComments.m", "w");

    if(fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);


    while((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1){
        /* for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
            test[i] = line;
            line++;
        }
        */

        //printf("%s", test);

        printf("%s", line);

        fprintf(fp2, "%s", line);
    }


    free(line);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: after if(fp == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE); you should add a if(fp2 == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

Comment: `line` points to the first character of the line...  what else do you need to know?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on your code. I added creation of a sample file and allocation of line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fp, *fp2;

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 1024;
    size_t read = 0;

    line = (char*) malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    if (line == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to allocate line...");
        exit(1);
    }
//Create sample file
    fp = fopen("taxDemo.m", "w+");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, "Non commented part of the line %i %% Commented \n", i);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("taxDemo.m", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("taxDemoNoComments.m", "w");

    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (line[i] == '%')
                line[i] = '\0';
        }

        printf("%s\n", line);

        fprintf(fp2, "%s\n", line);
    }
   free(line);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's really no need to do the allocation before calling `getline()`; it allocates quite happily given a null pointer and zero length, and generally allocates a reasonably large length (256 bytes, for example) when first called.  It typically even does that allocation when the first call to `getline()` returns -1 to indicate EOF.  It's important to free it, as you do.  Note that your inner `for` loop iterates over 1024 characters even if only 10 were read.  This is dubious.  When you write the null byte, you could/should break the inner loop too; there's no point continuing to search.

Comment: Also, there's a function called `strchr()` that might be useful.  And if a line doesn't have a comment attached, then you print a blank line — just saying.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Very good points, thanks a million for fixing my omissions!

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate over the contents of the line looking for `%` and do what you need to do when you find one.

   ```
   char* cp = line;
   for ( ; *cp != '\0'; ++cp )
   {
      if ( *cp == '%' )
      {
         // Do what you need to do.
         // If you want to ignore everything after the % but leave the %, use
         *(cp + 1) = '\0';

         // If you want to ignore % and everything after it, use
         *cp = '\0';
      }
   }

   // Print the line
   ```
2. I recommend using `fgets` instead of `getline` since `getline` is not a standard C library function.

   ```
   char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];   // #define MAX_LINE_LENGTH to suit your needs
   while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL ){
   ```

Comment: fgets doesn't return lines longer than MAX_LINE_LENGTH (which is probably shorter than the longest line). I coded my own getline function to overcome this problem, and if they are allowed to use such a function, it probably has the reason, that the teacher had something in mind like having them learn to code step by step and not by having them learn everything at once.

Comment: I did wight another program with fgets, which worked much nicer for me but my professor wants us to use getline().  Also sorry for the bad formatting, this is my first time asking a question.

Comment: @CiscoAbril, regardless of whether you use `getline` or `fgets` to read the data from the file, my suggestion/code for iterating over the contents of the line should work.

Comment: @RSahu thank you very much!  What would I end up using for the first part of the for loop?  for ( xxxx ; *cp != '\0'; ++cp )

Comment: I disagree with the opening recommendation, doubly so when the question is asking about the function explicitly.  If the question was using `fgets()` it would be fine not to mention `getline()` etc, but to suggest that they stop using what they are using seems — patronizing, or arrogant?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I didn't see it that way -- patronizing or arrogant. Not knowing what the OP's position, I think it is fair for us to recommend what we think is a better function to use. Of course. YMMV.

Comment: As post was originally tagged `getline`, recommending against `geltine` is , at best, a secondary issue.  Best to lead with the core issue about `%`.

Comment: @chux, that makes sense.